# Model not being displayed, But the shadow is

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to develop an app and started working on one that currently displays a 3d model on a surface using AR.

Everything was working well, until suddenly the image is not being displayed but the shadow is. I tried reverting the code to previous ones, but nothing worked.

Screen Shot: https://ibb.co/C6VrGbB

A shadow can be seen but not the model. I downloaded a model obj and added it. It worked fine at the beginning and suddenly the model stopped showing.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean tapExecuted = false;
    private final Object syncTaps = new Object();
    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private TextView debugText;

    private ArSceneView sceneView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        debugText = findViewById(R.id.debug_text);
        arFragment = (ArFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(this::handleTap);

        this.sceneView = this.arFragment.getArSceneView();
    }

    protected void handleTap(HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
//        this.debugText.setText(hitResult.getHitPose().toString());
        synchronized (this.syncTaps) {  // So that only one tap is validated at a time
            if (this.tapExecuted) {
                return;
            }
            this.tapExecuted = true;
        }
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, Uri.parse("axis test.sfb"))
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> addModelToScene(hitResult.createAnchor(), renderable))
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable -> {
                            Log.e("TAG", "Unable to load renderable");
                            return null;
                        });
    }

    private void addModelToScene(Anchor anchor, Renderable renderable) {
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        // To give User flexibility to move, resize and rotate the model
        TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(this.arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        // disabling resize and rotate
        transformableNode.getRotationController().setEnabled(false);
        transformableNode.getScaleController().setEnabled(false);
        transformableNode.setRenderable(renderable);
        transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
        transformableNode.select();
        this.sceneView.getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        this.debugText.setText("Model Added to the tap");
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to include the code that you are referencing so that people will be able to help you figure this out. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: updated with code\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was using an older version of sceneform. I guess it worked with the older version of software on the phone, but when it got updated it stopped working.

I updated sceneform from 1.8.0 to 1.11.0